# Совместное использование jquery и javascript в одном файле

Tags: javascript, jquery

Возможно ли совместное использование js и jquery кода в одном файле?

Comment: Возможно совместное использование js и jquery кода в одном файле.

Comment: jQuery это библиотека javascript-а а не отдельный какой-то язык программирования. Если возникает такой вопрос и вы хотите разобратся в програмиировании не используйте jQuery, все что есть в jQuery можно написать на javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, совместное использование js и jquery кода в одном файле возможно!